# OCaml record accessing itself

Tags: ocaml, record

I'm reading OCaml code where lots of records are defined. These records define functions for an interactive command line tool.

The type of these records is:

```
{
  name : string ;
  help : string ;
  run : string list -> unit
}
```

where `name` is the name of the command, `help` one little line of help for the function, and `run` a function that takes arguments and computes the result.

I would like to use the `name` field inside the `run` function. Is there a way to do that? Something like a `self.name`?

The tool must support `OCaml>4.00.1`.

Thanks

Comment: run is not a function, its a list of strings. If you want to use a record as an object, then why not just use an object?

Comment: Sorry, that was an error while writing my question. `run` **is** a function

Comment: That's a good question, but I don't know how old this code is. I'll take a look to see what OCaml objects are

Comment: Why does it matter how old the code is? Objects in OCaml are the O in OCaml.

Comment: It matter since it means I don't know who implemented this and why he's chosen this implementation. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can define a record recursively with the `rec` keyword, roughly speaking as long as all the fields are guaranteed to not involve an arbitrary computation. The following works:

```
type t = {
  name : string;
  help : string ;
  run : string list -> unit
}

let run x l =
  print_endline x.name

let rec x = {
  name = "a";
  help = "b";
  run = (fun l -> run x l);
}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
let rec x = {
  name = "a";
  help = "b";
  run = (run x);
}
```

Comment: Why not hide that run function?  let rec x =
  let run x l = print_endline x.name in
  {
    name = "a";
    help = "b";
    run = (fun l -> run x l);
  }

Comment: Because it's usually a good thing to not insert too much code between the beginning and the end of a definition (in this case `x`). Also usually I find there's no real advantage in hiding functions from the rest of the module. Hiding some members is useful for decluttering module interfaces, but that's done in an mli file.